# During an Interview was asked to define a 'field class'

Tags: c#, .net

During a telephone interview for a C# .net position I was asked to define 'what a field class is' (I asked them to repeat the question to ensure I heard them correctly).

I've heard of field's belonging to a class, never held of the term 'field class' before.

What was the interviewer looking for by asking that question?

---

Edit: I saw the Sharepoint library link in the msdn guide but it would have been very niche to expect that answer. The position didn't indicate any Sharepoint requirement and no talk of Sharepoint came up before or after the question.

Comment: Surely they meant for you to speak up and say the question was not meaningful.  The kind of trick question to filter out the fakers.

Comment: I have never heard of a "field class", I think either the interviewer was using some kind of non standard terminology or was asking you a nonsense question to see if you gave a nonsense answer.

Comment: If interview is about sharepoint. I guess [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is the one. Otherwise, You should have asked the interviewer. Also you sure that it is *field class* and not *class field* ?

Comment: This was a SharePoint interview?

Comment: I wonder if it relates to the concept of a [record class](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/Pattern-Matching)? Personally I'd have just 'fessed up and told them I had no clue what they were talking about. I'm a firm believer of being honest in what's missing from my knowledge, plus you cannot rule out that it's actually them who have no clue ;-)

Answer (score 3):

i think it's the name of a class. more info can be found here

[Field Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: That's pretty specific, surely the question would have been asked within the context of "within the sharepoint client library, what is a field class".  I am sure there are many libraries that could contain a class called Field.

Comment: I agree with Ben, the only other thing I could think of is an instance variable (private field).

Comment: may be the interview is regarding to sharepoint client.
if they wanna ask about private field they should say that what is field of class not 'field class' :)